# Change enabled map game modes CSGO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-workshop

I downloaded a map from the workshop for CSGO (I'm got it from steam.) And I like the map, but I would like to play deathmatches on it and it does not allow the deathmatch game mode by default. I know it is possible to change the game mode to deathmatch with the console while I'm in a match, but I would like to set the game mode before I start the match as I would any other mode. So how would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything before? There are several ways to setup game modes/types before loading the map, but I'm not sure about custom maps which are not designed for that. You can set game mode & type in your command line or in a map specific config (or even in your real config, if you wish to do so).

Comment: You could try contacting the creator as they can easily change it to a deathmatch map.

Answer (score 1):

You can forcibly execute a deathmatch game by typing this command in console:

```
game_mode 2;game_type 1;exec gamemode_deathmatch
```

You should also restart the match after typing that in. Type `mp_restartgame 1`
to restart.